# Closed Subset of $C[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Show that the following subset $D$ of $C[a,b]$ under the $max$ norm is a closed subset where every function $f \in D$ is such that $\int\limits_a^b f'(x)^2 + f(x)^2 dx \leq k$

Attempt at a solution:

I've already been able get an upper limit on everything except for $|f(a)|$.

We know that $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$ then $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$ using $a = f(x)$ and $b = f'(x)$ and integrating we see that $k \geq f(b)^2 - f(a)^2$.

But how could I proceed from here in order to isolate the $f(a)$?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that is $<k$ and not $\le k$ ?

Comment: In $C[a,b]$, what is $f'$? Did you mean $C^1[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes all of the functions are continuously differentiable as well.